# (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream. Only on some pages of the site. Puma, Nginx, Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, capistrano, digital-ocean, puma

I have a ruby on rails project and it's hosted on Digital Ocean droplet using Nginx, Puma, and Capistrano.
I'm taking over this project and there isn't a tracked repo of this project. So the only source code I have is on the remote server.
I had to restart the droplet server through D.O UI to access the console. After the restart, some of the pages were not loading (while some do). At this point, **zero** changes were made to the code base.
Looking at `production.log`, it spits out a common generic error for the pages that are not loading:

```
TypeError (no implicit conversion of nil into String):
...
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 11ms (Views: 10.0ms | Allocations: 3709)
```

So I dug deeper. This is what I get in `/var/log/nginx/error.log`:

```
2023/05/03 18:59:02 [crit] 16157#16157: *1 connect() to unix:///var/www/vhosts/myapp/shared/tmp/sockets/myapp-puma.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 100.11.109.141, server: ms.explore.myapp.com, request: "GET /users/sign_up HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://unix:///var/www/vhosts/myapp/shared/tmp/sockets/myapp-puma.sock:/users/sign_up", host: "ms.explore.myapp.com", referrer: "https://ms.explore.myapp.com/users/sign_up"
2023/05/03 18:59:03 [crit] 16157#16157: *1 connect() to unix:///var/www/vhosts/myapp/shared/tmp/sockets/myapp-puma.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 100.11.109.141, server: ms.explore.myapp.com, request: "GET /users/sign_up HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://unix:///var/www/vhosts/myapp/shared/tmp/sockets/myapp-puma.sock:/users/sign_up", host: "ms.explore.myapp.com", referrer: "https://ms.explore.myapp.com/users/sign_up"
2023/05/03 18:59:03 [crit] 16157#16157: *1 connect() to unix:///var/www/vhosts/myapp/shared/tmp/sockets/myapp-puma.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 100.11.109.141, server: ms.explore.myapp.com, request: "GET /users/sign_up HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://unix:///var/www/vhosts/myapp/shared/tmp/sockets/myapp-puma.sock:/users/sign_up", host: "ms.explore.myapp.com", referrer: "https://ms.explore.myapp.com/users/sign_up"
```

I've checked that `/var/www/vhosts/myapp/shared/tmp/sockets/myapp-puma.sock` exists.

This is /etc/nginx/sites-available/myapp:

```
upstream puma {
        server unix:///var/www/vhosts/myapp/shared/tmp/sockets/myapp-puma.sock;
}

server {
        listen 80;
        server_name ms.explore.myapp.com;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/ms.explore.myapp.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/ms.explore.myapp.com/privkey.pem;

        server_name ms.explore.myapp.com;

        root /var/www/vhosts/myapp/current/public;

        add_header X-Frame-Options "DENY";

        location ^~ /(assets|packs)/ {
                gzip_static on;
                expires max;
                add_header Cache-Control public;
        }

        location = /robots.txt {
                add_header Content-Type text/plain;
                return 200 "User-agent: *\nAllow: /\n";
        }

        try_files $uri/index.html $uri @puma;

        location @puma {
                proxy_pass http://puma;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }

        client_max_body_size 25M;

        rewrite ^/contacts/new$ /contact-us permanent;
        rewrite ^/program/resources/course-navigation$ /program/course-navigation permanent;
}
```

Running `ps aux | grep puma` shows that puma is connected to the correct sock file:

```
deploy   16523  0.0  5.8 410660 120276 ?       S    18:59   0:00 puma 3.12.1 (unix:///var/www/vhosts/myapp/shared/tmp/sockets/myapp-puma.sock)
deploy   16525  0.0  6.3 1161592 130524 ?      Sl   18:59   0:00 puma: cluster worker 0: 16523
deploy   16536  0.0  6.4 1161592 131408 ?      Sl   18:59   0:00 puma: cluster worker 1: 16523
deploy   19690  0.0  0.0  14860  1072 pts/1    S+   19:16   0:00 grep --color=auto puma
```

What could be happening here? I'm not too familiar with Capistrano and it's total functionality. I was suspecting that restarting the server could ignore Capistrano's automated set up steps, which could be configuring puma service workers and nginx server wrong.

I've tried restarting puma and nginx with `sudo service puma restart` and `sudo service nginx restart` respectively. As well as tried loading backup provided by D.O. But none seem to help.

I'm not able to do a deployment process as I don't have the source code locally.
Would greatly appreciate help from some server/ruby/rails experts! Thank you in advance!

**EDIT**
Here are more relevant information:
`config/deploy.rb`:

```
# config valid for current version and patch releases of Capistrano
lock "~> 3.17.0"

set :application, "myapp"
set :repo_url, "git@carney.codes:cra/myapp.git"

set :deploy_to, "/var/www/vhosts/myapp"


append :linked_files, "config/database.yml", "config/master.key", "config/features.yml"


append :linked_dirs, "log", "tmp/pids", "tmp/cache", "tmp/sockets", "public/system", "public/uploads", "vendor/bundle"


set :keep_releases, 3



set :keep_assets, 2
```

Here is also `config/deploy/ms-instance.rb`:

```
server "myapp-ms", user: "deploy", roles: %w(app db web)

set :puma_threads, [4, 16]
set :puma_workers, 2

set :pty,             true
set :use_sudo,        false
set :stage,           :production
set :puma_bind,       "unix://#{shared_path}/tmp/sockets/#{fetch(:application)}-puma.sock"
set :puma_state,      "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.state"
set :puma_pid,        "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.pid"
set :puma_access_log, "#{release_path}/log/puma.error.log"
set :puma_error_log,  "#{release_path}/log/puma.access.log"
set :puma_preload_app, true
set :puma_worker_timeout, nil
set :puma_init_active_record, true  # Change to false when not using ActiveRecord
```

**EDIT: 05/04/2023**

After restarting the server directly on Digital Ocean and also restarting nginx and puma, I no longer see the error I was receiving in `/var/log/nginx/error.log`. But I'm still getting Internal Error 500 for the pages I've been having trouble accessing.

I also made a double check to see if database is connected to the application and it is. I can see the database logs and there doesn't seem to be any abnormalities.

Comment: Let me start by saying thanks for providing a lot of relevant info! There's nothing obviously wrong I can see here. When this problem happens, did you try running `sudo service nginx restart` on all hosts. Does this resolve the issue?  If not, could you add your capistrano config? (just the deployment file should be enough)

Comment: Hi @MikeSzyndel! Thanks for taking your time to help out. Could I ask what you mean by running `sudo service nginx restart` on **all hosts**? I've ran that command in the remote server as well `sudo service puma restart`, which failed to resolve the issue. In the edit, I've included the files you've requested. Thanks again for your time!

Comment: Are you deploying to a single server, or are there multiple servers?

Comment: There is one server for this sub domain. So each instance of the application have their own server hosted on DO.

Comment: Why do you assume this has anything to do with nginx, puma or capistrano? The error says `TypeError (no implicit conversion of nil into String)` which is a Ruby exception. I'd start by getting the project up and running locally and see if I can reproduce the error there. Not debugging in production.

Answer (score 0):

Check the permission for the /var/www/vhosts/myapp/shared/tmp/sockets/myapp-puma.sock and check in nginx user have access to read and write the socket file.

Also share your config/puma.rb file Check the bind setting there and it's pointing to the same socket file.